# How to use the ContentValues in AIDL file

Tags: android

I am trying to use class `android.content.ContentValues` in an aidl
interface.  Since this class implements parcelable, why It is not possible to declare in the 
aidl file.so this is something particular to getting aidl to recognize a parcelable class.

Regards,

Jainish CS

Comment: All the classes which are implementing  Parcelable interface  eligible to get defined inside an AIDL file.So we can edit the platforms\version\framework.aidl file add the contentValues.So the problem is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the classes which are implementing Parcelable interface eligible to get defined inside an AIDL file.So we can edit the platforms\version\framework.aidl file add the contentValues.So the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

I find another better way to handle it:

1. create a package android.content in your sourcecode.
2. add&define an aidl file with name ContentValues.aidl:
3. Add the ContentValues.aidl with following code:
   package android.content;
   parcelable ContentValues;

Then the compile will show no error.